# htaccess: deny all ip starting with 209.209.209.*

Tags: security, .htaccess

I use htaccess to block unwanted ips. 
How can I block all ips starting with 209.209.209.*?

Will that work?

```
deny from 209.209.209.*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Deny from 209.209.209`, or `Deny from 209.209.209.0/255.255.255.0`. Don't forget to set the `Order` directive correctly (e.g. `Order Deny,Allow`). See the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) for details.